# Why are higher resolution Aruco tags less reliable?

Tags: opencv, aruco

I have observed that images of Aruco tags a very high resolution (compared to tag size) are actually less-reliably detected than average resolution.
I would have expected too-low resolution to be a problem, with no degradation.

Not a camera problem, I tested this with generated images (on a ChAruco board).

- Python: 3.10.5
- Aruco dictionary: DICT_6X6_100
- OpenCV library: opencv-contrib-python 4.6.0.66

I observe:

- Markers below 22px wide - resolution too low, so poor detection rate. OK.
- For markers that are between 22 and 26 pixels wide, we have 100% detection rate. Good.
- Above 26 pixels, the detection becomes sporadic, then falls below 50%. **Why??**

[image: Plot of #detected tags vs size for DICT_6X6_100]

Below are the actual detected tags. Note the perimeter tags are more consistently detected.
The images were rescaled to the same size after detection for this gif; you should see the resolution increase (and since the marker annotations are a fixed size, they appear to shrink)

[image: Animation of detected tags]

Extending this out to 300x300px:

[image]

Raw image for anyone wanting to test detection (ChAruco board DICT_6X6_100 at 60x60px, so each bit is 60/8=7.5px on average):

[image: ChAruco board DICT_6X6_100 at 60x60px]

For completeness, I tried the first 16 Aruco dictionaries and got this similar result:

[image: Aruco detection rate vs size for first 16 dictionaries]

As expected the 4X4 tags are more detectable at lower resolutions, but have an identical degradation at higher resolutions..?

This code tests detection vs marker size for predefined Aruco dictionaries on a ChAruco board:

```
import cv2
import cv2.aruco as aruco
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for dictNum in range(16):
    print(dictNum)
    d = aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(dictNum)
    arucoParams = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
    
    
    x = []
    y = []
    for markerLength in range(10, 60):
        # params
        markersX = 10                               # Number of markers in X direction
        markersY = 10                               # Number of markers in Y direction

        markerSeparation = round(markerLength/4)    #25% of marker size  
        margins = markerSeparation  
        borderBits = 1;              

        sc = (markerLength + markerSeparation)
        of = - markerSeparation + 2 * margins
        imageSize = [markersY*sc+of, markersX*sc+of]

        board = aruco.CharucoBoard_create(markersY, markersX, 1, markerLength/(markerLength+markerSeparation), d)
        imboard = board.draw(imageSize)
        
        fn = "chessboard" + str(dictNum) + "_" + str(markerLength) + ".tiff"
    ##    cv2.imwrite(fn, imboard)

        (corners, ids, rejected) = aruco.detectMarkers(imboard, d, parameters=arucoParams)

        x.append(markerLength)
        y.append(len(corners))
        if len(corners) > 0:

            length_of_axis = 0.02
            imboard = aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(imboard.copy(), corners, ids)

        fn = "ANNOchessboard" + str(dictNum) + "_" + str(markerLength) + ".tiff"
    ##    cv2.imwrite(fn, imboard)

    plt.plot(x, y, label="Dict#"+str(dictNum))
    plt.xlabel("Marker Size (px)")
    plt.ylabel("#Aruco Tags Detected")

plt.show()
```

Comment: My first thought was aliasing, where the variation in bit size is an issue. However it can't be this, since a 6X6 marker that is 80 pixels high has exactly 10 pixels per bit ((6+2)*10) and the detection reliability is poor, as demonstrated in the long tail. I think the perimeter being preferentially detected is important...

Comment: I'm betting it's the "quiet zone" around each marker (it's too small)... but whoever came up with those charucos should have thought of that. -- for your resizing I'd strongly recommend generating a high res picture and then downsampling it with INTER_AREA -- you could investigate whether the detection of the quads (not the pose recovery!) is already impaired. and investigate various parameters related to finding quads and refining edges/corners.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to christoph-rackwitz - the quiet zone is indeed too small.

I expanded my plot to 3D to see the effect of spacing between markers.
[image: 3D plot of aruco detection rate vs size and spacing]

I had used a Marker size of 0.8 (so the space between markers is 0.2, or 25% of the Marker size). For 100% detection, 28% is sufficient. I was so close! In ChAruco terms:

For a Square size of 1, the **Marker size must be *below* 0.78** for good detection rates on ideal images. I plan to use a larger spacing for printed pictures to have some margin.

```
aruco.CharucoBoard_create(markersY, markersX, 1, 0.78, dict); #0.78 or less
```

[image: Zoomed in of previous plot]

Comment: Hi, I am having a similar issue with detections in higher resolution images. I too had only a 25% gap between the checkerboard and the marker. It appears that many charuco targets that are printed use the same gap: For example, the 300mm x 200mm target printed by calib.io has 20mm checkerboard width with 16mm marker width. As its tricky to get these boards physically replaced, would you have any suggestions of what cv::aruco::DetectorParameters could be changed to improve the detections?

Comment: Just to answer my own question, the following parameters improve the detection numbers for high resolution images:

arucoParams.minMarkerPerimeterRate=0.01
arucoParams.minMarkerDistanceRate=0.001
arucoParams.minCornerDistanceRate=0.001

Answer (score 0):

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72904152/why-are-higher-resolution-aruco-tags-less-reliable#comment133543163_72921583) was the solution for me.

When creating a [CharucoDetector](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d9/df5/classcv_1_1aruco_1_1CharucoDetector.html#ad7647d1c3d0e2db97bedc31f743e796b) you can optionally pass in [detectorParams](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d1/dcd/structcv_1_1aruco_1_1DetectorParameters.html).
If you don't pass the parameters of leave them at their default values you can run into problems when trying to detect small/far away charuco boards in high-resolution images.
This is because of the minMarkerPerimeterRate parameter:

*determine minimum perimeter for marker contour to be detected.
This is defined as a rate **respect to the maximum dimension of the input image** (default 0.03).*

```
detector_params = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters()
detector_params.minMarkerPerimeterRate = 0.003 # default=0.03

charuco_detector = cv2.aruco.CharucoDetector(CHARUCO_BOARD, detectorParams=detector_params)
```

So if your image is for example 10000x10000 px then using the default value for  the minMarkerPerimeterRate means that the perimeter has to be at least 0.03*10000=300px.